# ActiveMQ Artemis does not deliver retain messages

Tags: activemq-artemis

I am struggling with a problem that ActiveMQ Artemis does not deliver retain messages within a topic.

At the time the message is sent to a topic no consumer is consuming the topic, but I would like to have that Artemis deliver the (last) retain message when the consumer connects to that topic.

This is my current address configuration:

```xml
         <address-setting match="#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes> -->
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>

            <redistribution-delay>0</redistribution-delay>


            <default-last-value-queue>true</default-last-value-queue>  
            <last-value-queue>true</last-value-queue>  
            <default-consumer-window-size>524288</default-consumer-window-size>  
            <auto-delete-addresses>true</auto-delete-addresses>
            <auto-delete-queues>true</auto-delete-queues>

            <auto-delete-queues-message-count>-1</auto-delete-queues-message-count>
            <auto-delete-queues-delay>0</auto-delete-queues-delay>
            <auto-delete-created-queues>true</auto-delete-created-queues>
            <default-purge-on-no-consumers>true</default-purge-on-no-consumers>
            <default-address-routing-type>MULTICAST</default-address-routing-type> 

            <max-size-bytes>10485760</max-size-bytes>  <!-- 10MB -->
            <page-size-bytes>1048576</page-size-bytes> <!-- 1MB -->
            <page-max-cache-size>2</page-max-cache-size>

         </address-setting>
```

Do you have any hint or solution for me?

Comment: Can you provide code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I do some investigation regarding the address-settings: when I delete <default-purge-on-no-consumers>true</default-purge-on-no-consumers> then I get retain messages and the RAM consumption increase

Comment: @justinBertram: What kind of code do you need? The whole Artemis broker.xml?

Comment: I'm talking about client code to reproduce the problem since you've already provided the configuration.